# How to compare two dates in C++

Tags: c++, function, date

I need to compare two dates.
The current date  with the user input one in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

So if expiry_date > current_date

display....
I have tried difftime() but that didnt work well since it uses a time parameter

```
time_t now;
  struct tm newyear;
  double seconds;

  time(&now);  /* get current time; same as: now = time(NULL)  */

  newyear = *localtime(&now);

  newyear.tm_hour = 0; newyear.tm_min = 0; newyear.tm_sec = 0;
  newyear.tm_mon = 0;  newyear.tm_mday = 1;

  seconds = difftime(now,mktime(&newyear));

  printf ("%.f seconds diff", seconds);
  system("pause");
```

heres a sample code i found

Comment: Could you please provide your code?

Comment: I think you need to use operator overload to compare dates like that

Comment: time_t now;
  struct tm newyear;
  double seconds;

  time(&now);  /* get current time; same as: now = time(NULL)  */

  newyear = *localtime(&now);

  newyear.tm_hour = 0; newyear.tm_min = 0; newyear.tm_sec = 0;
  newyear.tm_mon = 0;  newyear.tm_mday = 1;

  seconds = difftime(now,mktime(&newyear));

  printf ("%.f seconds diff", seconds);
  system("pause");

Comment: there is a boost date time library , i have never used it (but I trust boost)

Comment: I need to use visual c++

Answer (score 0):

If this is really a fixed format, you can do it with simple C string comparison

```
int date_cmp(const char *d1, const char *d2)
{
    int rc;
    // compare years
    rc = strncmp(d1 + 6, d2 + 6, 4);
    if (rc != 0)
        return rc;

    // compare months
    rc = strncmp(d1 + 3, d2 + 3, 2);
    if (rc != 0)
        return rc;

    // compare days
    return strncmp(d1, d2, 2);
}
```

Comment: where am i supposed to define value for d1 and d2 ? and in what format?

Answer (score 0):

Try strftime to parse the string into a tm*, then use mktime() and difftime().